# Iterating JSON using Jquery

Tags: jquery

I want to iterate and return a array to the Jquery autocomplete.Can you please suggest me how do I return the result term Raj and Rajesh in the array to autocomplete functionality.

```
{
    "responseHeader": {
        "status": 0,
        "QTime": 21
    },
    "command": "build",
    "suggest": {
        "mySuggester": {
            "R": {
                "numFound": 2,
                "suggestions": [
                    {
                        "term": "Raj",
                        "weight": 0,
                        "payload": ""
                    },
                    {
                        "term": "Rajesh",
                        "weight": 0,
                        "payload": ""
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the code below and feed the resulting autocomplete_data to jQuery autocomplete:

```
var data = { "responseHeader": { "status": 0, "QTime": 21 }, "command": "build", "suggest": { "mySuggester": { "R": { "numFound": 2, "suggestions": [{ "term": "Raj", "weight": 0, "payload": "" }, { "term": "Rajesh", "weight": 0, "payload": "" }] } } } };

var parentNode = data.suggest.mySuggester;
var suggestionsNode = null;
for (var key in parentNode) {
    suggestionsNode = parentNode[key].suggestions;
    if(suggestionsNode!=null)
        break;
}

var autocomplete_data = [];
$.each(suggestionsNode, function (i, val) {
    autocomplete_data.push(val.term);
});
console.log(autocomplete_data);
$("#autocomplete-container").autocomplete({
    source: autocomplete_data    
});
```

[jsFiddle Link](https://jsfiddle.net/3zc3sqgL/3/)

Comment: The problem is my R term keeps varying.How do I tackle that.

Comment: varies as in it changes from R to some other name or the contents of R changes from time to time? Do you have a choice to format your JSON response for better handling at server side?

Comment: Changes from R to Ra or some other term which the user typed.

Comment: hey Ajay, I have updated my answer to accommodate any naming variations for R. You can pay attention to this for loop: for (var key in parentNode) {}. Help me accept the answer and vote up if the answer works for you!